# Filtering the raster type in the arcpy.ListRasters() function

Tags: arcpy

After having read the Help file of the arcpy function: [ListRasters()](http://resources.arcgis.com/de/help/main/10.1/index.html#/na/018v0000003w000000/), I cannot find a better way of filtering the raster type than adding some extra python coding.

In detail, I have several files with the extension cfg and these are listed as rasters by the above function, I don't want these to be included. According to the Help file the following raster types can be used in order to isolate the search, but they are too generic: BMP, GIF, IMG, JP2, JPEG, JPG, PNG, TIF, GRID and All. So, is there any native 'ESRI' way of excluding the *.cfg raster files? is it a windows associated file type problem perhaps? Actually ArcCatalog 10.1 cannot open these cpg files.

By the way, this is how I am excluding the cfg ones:

```
for raster in arcpy.ListRasters():
    if raster[len(raster)-3:len(raster)] <> "CFG":
        ...
```

Overall I was wondering whether it would be possible achieving it by configuring some environment properties or not, not just by adding some extra python lines.

Comment: Yes, I did (See the edited post)

Comment: Out of curiosity what format are the rasters that you are trying to list, are they tiff or esri grids? Was wondering why there would be associated cfg files?

Comment: I am trying to list any raster format, but valid ones. *.cfg cannot be opened in Arcgis, this is why needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search on Google suggests these are nothing more than configuration files so I wondered why ArcCatalog was finding them. I went into the ArcCatalog options > rasters > file formats and discovered the *.cfg is actually a recognized raster format, see image below.

[image: Raster Formats]

A *fudge* to this problem is to untick this supported format and restart ArcCatalog. `arcpy` appears to honour this list of formats and the cfg files do not appear in the list.

The problem I see is removing supported file formats may be OK for you but if you are intending to give your code to a client they may actually be using it. So I think your solution of returning all rasters then filtering them is probably the safest.

Comment: or just create function to ignore a list of format (in this case *.cfg). Add or remove format is persistant. If other process need this format it can cause error.